# Email-to-case exceeds the data storage limit

Tags: email2case, emailtosalesforce

My Org primarily capturing correspondence by Email to case, The Inbox receives large amount of emails, that exceeds our data limits. Need to find a solution. We need to retain some data for compliance purpose and users would be pulling out the data reports.
How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really any way around this. You could consolidate some of your data or move it to a different system, but ultimately the only way to increase the data limits in Salesforce would be to purchase additional storage.